Error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equals')
Hello im trying to decode a possible MintToInstruction if there is one present in the transaction im looking at.
This is my code:
const { decodeMintToInstruction, decodeMintToCheckedInstruction, decodeInstruction } = require('@solana/spl-token');
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, TransactionInstruction } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');



//below is for getblock https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/GetBlockConfig.html
GetBlockConfig: {
  commitment: 'finalized';
  rewards: false;
  transactionDetails: "full";
}


//below is for get transactions if i need it later
GetVersionedBlockConfig: {
  commitment: 'finalized';
  maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0;
  rewards: false;
  transactionDetails: "full";
}


async function fetchCurrentSlot() {
  const currentSlot = await connection.getSlot();
  console.log('Current slot:', currentSlot);
  return currentSlot;
}


async function fetchBlock() {
  try {
      const currentSlot = await fetchCurrentSlot();
      const rawConfig = {
        encoding: 'json',
        maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
      }
      const block = await connection.getBlock(currentSlot,rawConfig );
      console.log(block);

      const transactionDetails = JSON.stringify(block.transactions[0].transaction, null, 2)
      console.log('First transactions details:', transactionDetails);

      const transactionInstructionData = block.transactions[0].transaction.message.instructions[0].data
      console.log('First transaction instructions data:',transactionInstructionData);


      //everything above here works 100%
      const mintInstructions = decodeMintToInstruction(transactionInstructionData)


      if (mintInstructions === null || mintInstructions === undefined) {
        console.log('Mint instructions not present in the transaction.');
      } else {
        console.log('Decoded mint instructions:', mintInstructions);
      }

  } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error :", error);
  }
}


fetchBlock();

And this is the error I keep getting
Error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equals')
    at decodeMintToInstruction (C:\Users\user\node_modules\@solana\spl-token\lib\cjs\instructions\mintTo.js:47:32)
    at fetchBlock (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\solanatest\solanatest.js:49:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Im really confused at what im doing wrong, I have also tried adding programId as another param and it still does not work.
The following is the source for the decodeMintToInstruction function im trying to use
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/instructions/mintTo.ts#L86-L111
I would appreciate some help with this as I have been stuck with this for a week now and I cant figure out whats wrong.
Thanks and have a nice day

You might want to use jsonParsed for the encoding in your config, that way you won't have to decode anything

@JonC I get the following error If i do that.
Error : SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get confirmed block: At path: transactions.0.transaction.message.accountKeys.0 -- Expected a string, but received: [object Object]
As the accountKeys array is an array of objects and not strings like it expects them to be
